# GetFirstChild in win32?

Tags: c, winapi, enumeration

I use EnumChildWindows to get all the Child windows from the main HWND window , But i would like to get only the first child of the given HWND window.

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc ( HWND hwndChild, LPARAM lParam)
{
  // logic to call only once 
}
```

Is it correct ? or any other simple way ?

~UK

Comment: Four answers at once--and all correct, I think...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc ( HWND hwndChild, LPARAM lParam)
{
  // process first child window
  return FALSE;
}
```

Alternatively, `HWND top_child = GetWindow(thisWindow, GW_CHILD);`

Comment: +1, I accept this answer . because this helps to get this one GetWindow(thisWindow,GW_HWNDFIRST) which I am using

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc ( HWND hwndChild, LPARAM lParam)
{
    /* do what you want with the first HWND */

    return FALSE; // stops enumeration.
}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633493(v=VS.85).aspx) for full details, but the relevant line is this:

> **Return Value**
>
> **BOOL**
>
> To continue enumeration, the callback
>   function must return **TRUE**; to stop
>   enumeration, it must return **FALSE**.

Answer (score 2):

[GetWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633515(VS.85).aspx)(...,GW_CHILD) will give you the window at the top of the z-order which I assume is what you are after